# Trying to run mkvmerge from powershell

Tags: powershell

I trying to run a mkvmerge command from powershell that join a srt and ts file to mkv file. It going to loop the files to merge. I start simple and have only 01.srt and 01.ts in a folder

I have try to put quote at the program to see if it works. I have now split the command line so it easy for me to see how it works and also use write-host to see the output of the variable I have join.

```bsh
$myprogram="${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge"
$myoutput="-o E:\TV\TS\klar\" + $_.BaseName + ".mkv"
$mysource="E:\TV\TS\klar\" + $_.BaseName + ".ts"
$mysubtitle="--language 0:swe --forced-track 0:yes E:\TV\TS\klar\" + $_.BaseName + ".swe.srt"
Write-Host $myprogram $myoutput $mysource $mysubtitle
& $myprogram $myoutput $mysource $mysubtitle
```

I expect it going to take the ts and srt file to a mkv file.
The error I get is

```bsh
C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge -o E:\TV\TS\klar\01.mkv E:\TV\TS\klar\01.ts --language 0:swe --forced-track 0:yes E:\TV\TS\klar\01.swe.srt
mkvmerge v36.0.0 ('Is That Jazz?') 64-bit
Error: no destination file name was given.
```

As you can see it have a destination file name (01.mkv)
If I take the output and add quote around the program like this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge" -o E:\TV\TS\klar\01.mkv E:\TV\TS\klar\01.ts --language 0:swe --forced-track 0:yes E:\TV\TS\klar\01.swe.srt
```

and run it from command prompt then it works

/UPDATE
I have got it to work. I did found someone else use powershell and mkvmerge and that person did put the option outside the variable :)

Comment: You do not show how you create your pipeline variable ($_).

Comment: Well yes because it was not the problem with the code because I can see it read the file 01. But I did find how to fix it if I put the option outside the variable :)